# Hosting a local website to the public using a VPN?

Tags: vpn, django

Is it possible to host a local website for a select number of people who I give access to my VPN address?

My thought process is this. I will get a Windows computer to host a VPN network, and with the same computer, I would also host a MySQL server and a Django (or any other framework) application on `192.168.1.2:8000` (my static local IP).

Then provide my VPN IP address to my users who can use something like Cisco AnyConnect to connect to my VPN and view my site on something like `192.168.1.2:8000`.

Is this feasible? Am I missing anything? Do I need a special router to maintain a static IP address? Would using a residential vs private internet make a difference?

Comment: Yes this is feasible - the only suggestion I would make would be to create a different IP address range on your VPN server, this is so there's less risk of your server's IP clashing with one on their network. (There's probably just under a 50% chance they too are running on the 192.168.1.0/24 segment)

Comment: by "their" network you mean my ISP?

Comment: No - so your server's IP (192.168.1.2) is a private address (all IPs in 192.168.0.0/16 are classed as private) and are thus not publically routable, this means though that subnets like 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 are used _privately_ for internal hosts by almost all consumer routers. If you create a VPN server and provide a third party with your private IP address, there's a good chance his network will have a host with the same IP as that one and his computer may decide to route to the local one not yours. Creating a range along the lines of 10.0.0.0/24 should work around it though.

Comment: If users not connected to your intranet either directly or through a VPN that is, can access the website, then it is no longer considered a local website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Feasibility depends on your setupp, budget and other factors, so it would be difficult to decide based on the information you have provided. If you are using Cisco Anyconnect, then you will need Cisco ASA or Cisco router running IOS image that supports VPN Remote access. There will be additional cost for Anyconnect users. Static IP address provides more reliable connection, but you can use Dynamic IP also, by using Dynamic DNS service. Residential Vs. Private will depend on your needs, like Reliability, Bandwidth and so on.